# How to insert a line break into a string variable to be displayed in a pre or code tag?

Tags: html, angular, pre

I know that there are lots of questions about line breaks in `pre` and `code` tags, but they all seem to concern string literals. However, I want to display a string variable that I get from a HTTP request. The string represents a code snippet and will look like this: `console.WriteLine("Hello");\nconsole.WriteLine("World");\nconsole.WriteLine("Bye");\n`

My problem is that when I put this into a `pre` or `code` tag like this:

```
<pre>
    {{ code }}
</pre>
```

it displayes as

```
console.WriteLine("Hello");\nconsole.WriteLine("World");\nconsole.WriteLine("Bye");\n
```

instead of

```
console.WriteLine("Hello");
console.WriteLine("World");
console.WriteLine("Bye");
```

Replacing `\n` with `<br>` also doesn't help, and I didn't have any luck with css settings either. I could in theory change the backend to not put `\n` at the end of every line, but I have no idea how I would denote a line break then.

Comment: That's the difference between _code_, and _data_. A `\n` gets interpreted as a newline in _code_ - but if you have _data_ that contains the _characters_ `\n`, nothing will interpret those a "special" any more at this point. So replace the sequence of the characters backslash and `n` with a _real_ backslash in your variable, before you pass this on to the template.

Comment: But if you are receving this value via an HTTP request, then you should be able to place an _actual_ line break in there already. Your server-side code apparently did not do that, but inserted the characters backslash followed by `n`.

Comment: @CBroe And how do I place an actual line break?

Comment: @traynor What's the difference?

Comment: I don't know what your backend does, but it looks like you made it add the two characters backslash and `n`, instead of an actual line break.

Comment: @CBroe I don't understand. What do you mean with "actual line break"? As far as I know `\n` is how you denote a line break (or <br> in HTML but that doesn't work here either). How else would I put a line break into a string?

Comment: I did try to explain this in my first comment already ... _"As far as I know \n is how you denote a line break"_ - yes - in _code_. But you are not working in code here, you have _data_ that you are receiving from an external source. That data does not get interpreted as code - and therefor, `\n` does not get interpreted as a line break either, but is considered just a backslash followed by the letter `n`.

Comment: You need to either make sure that what you _receive_ via HTTP contains an actual line break already; or _replace_ the sequence "backslash followed by `n`" with an actual line break on the client side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I made it work by calling `replaceAll("\\n", "\n")` on the code string.